# asp.net mvc: make RedirectToAction(string, object) into RedirectToAction<Controller>(x => x.Detail(id))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

anybody knows how to make a method (I will put it in a extensions class) that will do the same as the mvc's RedirectToAction only using expressions (no magic strings).

So that instead of writing something like this:

```
 RedirectToAction("Detail", 
    new RouteValueDictionary { {"messageId", messageId}});
```

I would do like this:

```
this.RedirectToAction(x => x.Detail(messageId));
```

I tried and did something like this but I don't know how to add the parameters:

```
 public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(this T controller,
     Expression<Action<T>> expression)
 {
     return RedirectToAction(
        (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvcContrib has it: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction

Comment: Aaaah, contrib not futures.  +1

Comment: this contrib is on mvc2, and I'm still using mvc 1

Comment: MVC1 release is also there, for example http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=33401.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2008/04/07/59274.aspx

Also, I believe they moved type-safe HtmlHelper extensions into the MVC Futures assembly back when 1.0 came out, however I can't seem to find it now.