# How to avoid using hard coded string literals when invoking, for example, RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When invoking `Html.DisplayNameFor`, we just provide a lambda expression to render, for example, the student name via `item => Model.Name`.
This approach is very good because of compile-time check.

How to make it possible as well for `RedirectToAction`, for example, `RedirectToAction(controller => Controllers.Student.Index)` rather than `RedirectToAction("Index")`? Assume the property named `Controllers` containing all controllers used in the project.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102757/asp-net-mvc-make-redirecttoactionstring-object-into-redirecttoactioncontrol    Those libraries look quite old though, I don't know if they still work with the latest versions of ASP.NET

Comment: If property Controllers.Student.Index is correct (or somehow you can get to similar property) you can simply use RedirectToAction(nameof( Controllers.Student.Index))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

As variant - create CoolControllerBase inheritor from ControllerBase and add Controllers property. All controllers should inherit CoolControllerBase. Populate Controllers property using reflection in static constructor: GetAssembly, GetClasses inherited CoolControlelrBase, GetMethods for each class.

Other variant - achieve the same with Roslyn.

Third variant: use nameof.

```
RedirectToAction(nameof(Student), nameof(Student.Index))
```

But what is your goal? Do you want autocomplete?

Comment: I want to get the compile time check and IntelliSense support.